# SQL Exists command

Tags: mysql, hibernate, exists, not-exists, notin

I have a query that I want to optimize. I want to try with 'EXISTS' command, instead of 'IN' command, but whenever I try to implement 'EXISTS', it returns more rows than it should.

Query with 'IN':

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM echosign_devbox.participation as p
left join echosign_devbox.agreement as a
on p.agreement_id=a.agreement_id
where a.status not in ('SIGNED', 'ABANDONED', 'EXPIRED', 'ABANDONED_BEFORE_SEND');
```

Does anyone know how should I change, just to be with 'EXISTS' command? Thanks!

Comment: *but whenever I try to implement 'EXISTS', it returns more rows than it should.* Show your attempt, even incorrect one. PS. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Do you get the "correct" answer if you remove the word "LEFT"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  count(*)
    FROM  echosign_devbox.participation as p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
            FROM echosign_devbox.agreement as a
            WHERE  p.agreement_id = a.agreement_id
              AND  a.status IN ('SIGNED', 'ABANDONED', 'EXPIRED', 'ABANDONED_BEFORE_SEND' ) );
```

`a` needs `INDEX(agreement_id, status)`

Would this give the 'correct' answer?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM echosign_devbox.agreement
    WHERE status NOT IN ('SIGNED', 'ABANDONED', 'EXPIRED', 'ABANDONED_BEFORE_SEND')
```

What is the relationship between the tables?  1:1?  1:many?